# Returning the modified object in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to make a chainable method such that I can write:

```
@blog = Blog.new.set_user(current_user).save
```

instead of

```
@blog = Blog.new
@blog.user = current_user
```

I have defined the following method inside the model:

```
def set_user(user)
  self.user = user
  return self
end
```

except that it doesn't work. How do I make a method to return the updated instance so that further chaining can be done upon it?

**UPDATE:**
My bad, here's what I was doing wrong: The chainable method was named "user" and so it was conflicting with the model's own `blog.user` method. I changed the name to something unique and voila! it works.

Comment: Would you object to passing in your values as a hash directly to the .new method? For example: `@blog = Blog.new(:user=>current_user)`. Or is there another reason you'd like to chain?

Comment: @Teeg Yes, I'm trying to learn how one could write methods that can be chained.

Comment: I'm not sure you can make it work exactly like you want. Honestly, if you have no practical reason to chain in the exact way you're looking for, don't do it. In ruby, the most similar fashion of achieving the chaining thing is the hash attributes I pointed out. The other issue is that the .save method returns a boolean, so you'd have to override that method, and have it return self, which is extra work and complication with no benefit. As MrYoshiji pointed out, the create method can be used to achieve the one-line .new and .save operation, but you still end up using the attribute hash thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to avoid this in Rails and use the models associations and scopes to do part of the work:

```
@blog = current_user.blogs.create
```

About the question you asked, returning self should do the work idd, can you write the output of the console when you create the blog and also let us know what is the output of:

```
@blog.inspect
```

Maybe the error is somewhere else...

Comment: I'd write something like your code too. Infact in my question I've just given an example and the question is only conceptual.

Answer (score 1):

Your `set_user` method should return a user instance. `self` in this context is `Blog`

```
def set_user(user)
  user
end
```

If you are using Rails and there is an association between `Blog` and `User` you are already able to do

`blog.user` or `blog.users` based on what type of association you have in between these models.

Comment: I, too,  expect `self` to return the instance itself. It doesn't. Plus the methods `blog.user` you get from defining an association is not chainable.

Comment: Ok, I see what you are getting at here. Can you do `Blog.new.set_user(current_user).inspect` and share the output? Keeping your original code?

Comment: it's ironic that the code in my question works and the slightly different version I'm using in my application was flawed. Thanks anyway.